# Saving legend from grid.draw without space next to legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to exctact the legend from a plot:

```
a<-rnorm(100)
b<-runif(100)
ba<-cbind(a,b)
colnames(ba)<-c("a","b")
ba<-melt(ba,id.vars=1:1)
colnames(ba)<-c("c","variable","value")
plot1<-ggplot(q,aes(x=c,y=value,colour=variable,size=variable))+geom_point()+theme(legend.position="right")
```

Now I extract the legend from the grob:

```
g_legend<-function(a.gplot){
tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot))
leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
return(legend)}


legend<-g_legend(plot1)
```

I can save this legend by using grid.draw:
    pdf("plot.pdf")
    grid.draw(legend)
    dev.off()

The resulting image will contain the legend with a lot of white space. Is there a way to plot only the legend but not to have so much space next to it?

Comment: I think using `pdf` or `png` does work.  `ggsave` probably doesn't work because the output of `grid.draw` isn't a ggplot object.

Comment: right, but what should I put after pdf? pdf(grid.draw(legend))? or how?

Comment: `pdf("filename.pdf")`, then all your plotting commands, then `dev.off()`

Comment: thanks, this is great. See my edit. I have added a reproducible example and I have specified a further question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gg <- gtable::gtable_filter(x=ggplotGrob(plot1), 
               pattern="guide", trim=TRUE)[["grobs"]][[1]][["grobs"]][[1]]

pdf("legend.pdf", 
    width=convertWidth(sum(gg$width), "in", valueOnly=TRUE),
    height=convertHeight(sum(gg$heights), "in", valueOnly=TRUE))
grid.draw(gg)
dev.off()
```

Comment: this is much better now, but there's still a lot of space around.

Comment: `?theme`  You need to do some googling and leg work yourself.  Like when I suggested `pdf`.  If you don't get how to use it at least try `?pdf`.

Comment: there's an issue with the legend margins, some of it is not customizable (see github issue tracker).